# Lifetime specifiers and generics in SFML

Tags: rust, sfml

I'm trying to wrap my head around trait bounds and lifetime specifiers but I do not really get what is wrong here.

```
fn render_screen<'a, T>(window: &mut RenderWindow, chip: &mut Chip, rect: &'a mut T)
where
    T: Shape<'a> + Drawable,
{
    window.clear(&Color::BLACK);
    for x in 0..SCREEN_COLUMNS {
        for y in 0..SCREEN_ROWS {
            if chip.vid_mem[y][x] == 1 {
                let x_pos = (x * SCALE) as f32;
                let y_pos = (y * SCALE) as f32;
                &mut rect.set_position((x_pos, y_pos));
                window.draw(&rect);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&'a mut T: sfml::graphics::Drawable` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:114:29
    |
114 |                 window.draw(&rect);
    |                             ^^^^^ the trait `sfml::graphics::Drawable` is not implemented for `&'a mut T`
    |
    = note: required for the cast to the object type `sfml::graphics::Drawable`
```

I don't really know how to specify my question any more than that since I have only been writing Rust for about 3 weeks and am still pretty new to the language.

Comment: Please do not attempt to "interpret" or "describe" the error message for us. Paste the *entire* thing. That way it has everything important (error code, the lines that point exactly where the problem is, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

> `` the trait bound `&'a mut T: sfml::graphics::Drawable` is not satisfied ``

That's because it isn't — all you have required is that `T` implements `Drawable`:

```
T: Shape<'a> + Drawable,
```

`T`, `&T` and `&mut T` are all different types; just because `T` implements a trait doesn't mean that `&mut T` does. If you need to place a restriction on the mutable reference to a `T`, you can:

```
fn render_screen<'a, T>(window: &mut RenderWindow, chip: &mut Chip, rect: &'a mut T)
where
    T: Shape<'a>,
    for <'a> &'a mut T: Drawable,
```

You might also be able to accept a `T` with the appropriate bounds:

```
fn render_screen<'a, T>(window: &mut RenderWindow, chip: &mut Chip, mut rect: T)
where
    T: Shape<'a> + Drawable,
```

and then just pass in a `&mut Foo` wherever it is called.